# Finding $T^\dagger$ where $T\varphi(x)=\varphi(x+a)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Finding $T^\dagger$ where $T\varphi(x)=\varphi(x+a)$. It is a pretty straightforward and I imagine easy question.

Comment: You need to define the problem mathematically. What ia the space (set) on which T acts and in which phi is? Does one have a scalar product in this space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will only give you a hint. The adjoint $T^\dagger$ is defined by the property
$$ ( \psi, T\varphi ) = (T^\dagger\psi, \varphi) $$
for all wave functions $\psi, \varphi$.
Here, $(\psi, \varphi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)^\ast \varphi(x) \, \mathrm dx$ is the inner product.

In other words: given a function $\psi(x)$, you must find another function $f(x)$ so that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)^\ast \varphi(x+a) \, \mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^\ast \varphi(x) \, \mathrm dx $$
for all $\varphi$.
If you can find such a function $f$, then $T^\dagger \psi = f$.